# Cannot load file or assembly System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have two projects in one solution. One is a class library that has three nuget packages installed: HtmlAgilityPack, Microsoft.Syndication, and IrcDotNet. The other is the startup project, a console application project with only one Nuget Package installed, Microsoft.Syndication. This project also has a dependency on the class library. When I run the startup project, I get an exception with the following details.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Source=   StackTrace:    at
>   AlexiConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\myself\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Alexi\AlexiConsole\Program.cs:line 21
>
> Inner Exception 1: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I don't know why. I already have binding redirects in the app.config of both projects for redirecting versions 0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0 to 4.1.0.0.

Both project target .NET 4.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue myself. I recreated both projects, targeting .NET 4.7, and the issue was resolved.

Maybe the problem was that I originally targeted an earlier version of .NET and then changed the version. But I am not sure.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Answer (score 6):

I have face same issue, My issue is

> ```
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

To Solve this issue, Comment assembly `<dependentAssembly></dependentAssembly>` which Contain `culture="neutral"` in Web.config File and Rebuild Application. My application run properly and Problem Solve.

Comment: thanks! unbelievable that is actually works!

Answer (score 3):

I had faced the same issue. Just follow these steps to solve your problem

- Right Click on your solution and choose `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`
- In the `Installed` tab search `System.Runtime`
- Now you can see in which projects you have installed the library
- Select proper projects and **downgrade** `System.Runtime` to the previous version and **upgrade** it again
- Clean & Rebuild your solution
- Run project

It should works now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my WPF executable started crashing when I made a Grpc call. It turns out the project's `app.config` file contained some assembly bindings left over from IDK what (VS 2019 16.3 update? NuGet update?). After I deleted them, it worked again.

### Exception

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=System.Memory
  StackTrace:
   at System.SpanHelpers.PerTypeValues'1.MeasureArrayAdjustment()
   at System.SpanHelpers.PerTypeValues'1..cctor()`

`Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

---

### App.config

Delete these bindings:

`<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>`

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone in the future.**

You can also try deleting your temporary ASP.NET Files, look for this folder:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[yourversionNumber]\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Also, try this one

C:\Users[YourUser]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files