# Mono MSC C# compiler how to add assembly references

Tags: c#, c++, mono

So im trying to run a .NET C# script in mono , but i get errors of missing assemblies...

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\callCsharp-fromCPP\CMonoTest\Mp3ToSpeech.cs(1,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Speech' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\callCsharp-fromCPP\CMonoTest\Mp3ToSpeech.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NAudio' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\callCsharp-fromCPP\CMonoTest\SeleniumWebdriver.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `OpenQA' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
...
```

here is my current C++ code

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <filesystem>


#pragma comment(lib, "mono-2.0-boehm.lib") // replaced from mono-2.0.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "mono-2.0-sgen.lib") // It is new with GC code library GC from Gnu Compilication
#pragma comment(lib , "MonoPosixHelper.lib")

std::string get_working_path()
{
    char temp[260]; // max windows path length
    return (_getcwd(temp, sizeof(temp)) ? std::string(temp) : std::string(""));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#pragma region Load and compile the script
    std::string Mp3Path = std::filesystem::path(get_working_path()).parent_path().string() + R"(\CMonoTest\ChromeDriverInstaller.cs  )";
    std::string ProgramPath = std::filesystem::path(get_working_path()).parent_path().string() + R"(\CMonoTest\Program.cs  )";
    std::string ChromeInstPath = std::filesystem::path(get_working_path()).parent_path().string() + R"(\CMonoTest\Mp3ToSpeech.cs  )";
    std::string SeleniumWebPath = std::filesystem::path(get_working_path()).parent_path().string() + R"(\CMonoTest\SeleniumWebdriver.cs  )";
    //C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\dotnetseleniumextras.waithelpers\3.11.0\lib\net45\SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.dll
    //C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\naudio\2.1.0\lib\net6.0\NAudio.dll
    //C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\selenium.support\4.4.0\lib\net5.0\WebDriver.Support.dll
    //C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\selenium.webdriver\4.4.0\lib\net5.0\WebDriver.dll
    //C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\system.speech\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\System.Speech.dll
    std::string references = R"(-r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\dotnetseleniumextras.waithelpers\3.11.0\lib\net45\SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.dll
    -r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\naudio\2.1.0\lib\net6.0\NAudio.dll -r:/C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\selenium.support\4.4.0\lib\net5.0\WebDriver.Support.dll
    -r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\selenium.webdriver\4.4.0\lib\net5.0\WebDriver.dll -r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\system.speech\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\System.Speech.dll)";
    std::string command = "mcs " + ProgramPath + ChromeInstPath + SeleniumWebPath + Mp3Path + references + R"( -target:library)";
    
    //Compile the script
    std::string Command = std::string(R"(cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin && )") + command;
    system(Command.c_str());
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Init mono runtime
    mono_set_dirs("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mono\\lib",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mono\\etc");

    //Init a domain
    MonoDomain* domain;
    domain = mono_jit_init("MonoScriptTry");
    if (!domain)
    {
        std::cout << "mono_jit_init failed" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    //Open a assembly in the domain
    MonoAssembly* assembly;
    std::string assemblyPath = std::filesystem::path(get_working_path()).parent_path().string() + R"(\CMonoTest\Program.dll)";
    assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, assemblyPath.c_str());
    if (!assembly)
    {
        std::cout << "mono_domain_assembly_open failed" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    //Get a image from the assembly
    MonoImage* image;
    image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);
    if (!image)
    {
        std::cout << "mono_assembly_get_image failed" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Run a static method
    {
        //Build a method description object
        MonoMethodDesc* TypeMethodDesc;
        const char* TypeMethodDescStr = "Program:StartWebRegister()";
        TypeMethodDesc = mono_method_desc_new(TypeMethodDescStr, NULL);
        if (!TypeMethodDesc)
        {
            std::cout << "mono_method_desc_new failed" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            return 1;
        }

        //Search the method in the image
        MonoMethod* method;
        method = mono_method_desc_search_in_image(TypeMethodDesc, image);
        if (!method)
        {
            std::cout << "mono_method_desc_search_in_image failed" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            return 1;
        }

        //run the method
        std::cout << "Running the static method: " << TypeMethodDescStr << std::endl;
        mono_runtime_invoke(method, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    }
#pragma endregion


#pragma endregion

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Im trying to reference assemblies using -r: , using full path where they are located , but it doesnt work and i still get errors.

1. I Tried using msbuild , to build .csproj with instead of msc (see my other question [Embedding mono in C++ , Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73443516/embedding-mono-in-c-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-or-one)) but it cant call the static method

So my question is how can i reference the assemblies. Is there a easy way to do that in mono  if you are using nuget? I saw on the docs that you can call packages using -pkg: if they have a .pc file (which none of .nuget have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have also problems with this , my problem was that

```cpp
std::string references = R"(-r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\dotnetseleniumextras.waithelpers\3.11.0\lib\net45\SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.dll
    -r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\naudio\2.1.0\lib\net6.0\NAudio.dll -r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\selenium.support\4.4.0\lib\net5.0\WebDriver.Support.dll
    -r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\selenium.webdriver\4.4.0\lib\net5.0\WebDriver.dll -r:C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\system.speech\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\System.Speech.dll)";
```

wasnt respecting this format

```bash
msc -r:"reference\to\assembly.dll"
```

it should be in quotes even if the path doesnt have any spaces.
This is a problem *only* when you want to use full path , as

```bash
msc -r:System.Assembly.dll
```

works fine!